# How to link an external library with cmake?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I am trying to build a project using CMake. One of the libraries that is required for the project is located on a path outside my project directory. The header files are scattered in sub-directories as well as in the root of the folder. A bit like this:

```
/some_remote_path/packages/BOOX/
               |-> foo.h
               |-> banana.h
               |-> orange.h
               |-> timer
                     |-> lib0.h
                     |-> lib1.h
                     |-> lib2.h
               |-> types
                     |-> type0.h
                     |-> type1.h
                     |-> type2.h
               ...
```

I am trying to link these using the following command:

```
include_directories (${SOME_OTHER_LIB_HEADERS} ${BOOX_HEADERS})
```

How can I store all the headers into the `${BOOX_HEADERS}` variable? I tried many things such as various macros utilising the `GLOB_RECURSE` feature:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE ${BOOX_HEADERS} ${path_to_boox_lib} *.h)
```

But without any success. I would like to skip writing a complex `find.cmake` script. That would have helped me (probably?) to generate something like ${BOOX_INCLUDE_DIRS}. What would be the best solution to simply construct the header list and pass it to the compiler using CMake.

Comment: You are not linking anything by including headers. For headers in multiple location, you can assign a list to a variable

Comment: Yes, how can I create the list variable by recursively collecting all the header files? I should edit my question to make this clearer. Once I solve this, I will move on to the lib files.

Comment: You should not collect any header files, `*.h`. The include_directories is for directories containing header files. You need to to execute include_directories for the BOOX directory, the timer and the types, unless you include lib0.h using `#include <BOOX/timer/lib0.h>. Then you only need the top-directory BOOX

Comment: So I have to manually specify each subfolder?

Comment: Yes, or just the top folder, if you append `timer` and `types` in your includes. The `include_directories` is for directories not headers

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to link these using the following command:

you are including header with the command you have given how would you also need to define LIBs path for the library with `link_directories(directory1 directory2 ...)`